# Dynamically change your options in a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

I'm trying to recreate a form builder like http://bootsnipp.com/forms.
I'm having a hard time figuring out how to change the options in the modal so that when you click save, it will update the options in the dropdown menu, as seen in the picture

[image]
Below is my code so far:

```
<div id ="doctordrop" class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="buttondropdown" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="default" id="default">Default</label>

        <div class="col-md-9">                                        
            <select id="options" class="form-control select">
                <option id="op">Option 1</option>
                <option id="op">Option 2</option>
                <option id="op">Option 3</option>
                <option id="op">Option 4</option>
                <option id="op">Option 5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- DROP DOWN Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Drop Down Menu</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                    <div id="textfield" class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Label Name</label>  
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="labelname" id="defaultLabel" placeholder="put previous input name here" value=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Text area</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <textarea class="form-control field" data-type="textarea-split" id="options">Option one Option two</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="replaceDefault();">Save</button>

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this would be easy if you use AngularJS

Comment: You are creating a lot of unnecessary work for yourself. What I have done is placed each element's attributes in a JSON file and then built up the dialog contents using JavaScript. This way the app becomes more flexible, easier to maintain and update.